# Decoding (javascript) source maps

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I have been puzzling over the following image found [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

[image: Decoding the source map]

And the following description how it was supposed to work:

> The above diagram AAgBC once processed further would return 0, 0, 32, 16, 1 – the 32 being the continuation bit that helps build the following value of 16. B purely decoded in Base64 is 1. So the important values that are used are 0, 0, 16, 1. This then lets us know that line 1 (lines are kept count by the semi colons) column 0 of the generated file maps to file 0 (array of files 0 is foo.js), line 16 at column 1.

I vaguely understands why `B` was converted to `16`, but what is `C`? and how did that get converted to `1`?

Comment: have you figured that out?

Answer (score 3):

The explanation on that page is very confusing. A key thing it forgets to mention is that the base64 and VLQ system is based on a 6-bit alphabet instead of the usual 8-bit alphabet; for example the base64 data is incompatible with "normal" base64 decoders like JavaScript's own `atob` function (`atob("AAgBC")` produces an error). I think [this page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidni/2016/03/14/source-maps-under-the-hood-vlq-base64-and-yoda/) offers a better explanation.

Suppose we have a function `decodeLine()` to decode the numbers for a single line, `"IACH,mBAA0B,CAAS,EAAE,SAAgB"`. This is only half the battle, as each of the arrays-of-4 (or arrays-of-5) is relative to the previous array-of-4.

In this example the first base64 string "IACH" represents the array `[4,0,1,-3]`, but this information is useless by itself because it is relative to the previous array-of-4 (except for the first number, which is reset to 0 at the beginning of each line). So if the sum of the previous arrays-of-4 was `[11,1,10,3]`, we can compute that the real meaning of "IACH" is `[4, 1+0, 10+1,3+-3] = [4,1,11,0]` - which means "output column 4 corresponds to source file 1, source line 11, source column 0". Similarly, "mBAA0B" decodes to [19,0,0,26] which is added to [4,1,11,0] to get [23,1,11,26] which means "output column 23 corresponds to source file 1, source line 11, source column 26".

So here I have written code to decode an entire `"mappings"` string. It has two parts, `decodeLine` to decode a single line and `scanMappings` to decode all the lines and call a function for each decoded set of 6 values (line, column, source file, source line, source column, and optional name index):

```js
function decodeLine(line) { 
  function digit(c) { return atob("AAA"+c).charCodeAt(2); }
  if (line==="") return [];
  return line.split(",").map(token => {
    var output = [], num;
    for (var i = 0; i < token.length;) {
      var v = 0, shift = 0;
      do {
        var d = digit(token[i++]);  // d = next 6-bit value decoded from base64
        v |= (d & 31) << shift;     // put lowest 5 bits of d into v
      } while (shift += 5, d & 32); // repeat if high bit of d is set
      output.push(v & 1 ? -(v >> 1) : v >> 1); // low bit is sign
    }
    return output;
  });
}
function scanMappings(data, callback) {
  var lines = data.split(";"), output = [];
  var sum = [0,0,0,0,0];
  for (var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++) {
    sum[0] = 0;
    decodeLine(lines[line]).forEach(p => {
      for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) sum[i] += p[i];
      callback(line, ...sum);
    })
  }
}

// Example taken from one of my TypeScript files
console.log(JSON.stringify(decodeLine("IACH,mBAA0B,CAAS,EAAE,SAAgB")));
scanMappings(
 ";;;;;;;;;;;ICAA;;;;;;;;;;OAUG;IACH,mBAA0B,CAAS,EAAE,SAAgB;QACnD,uEAAuE",
  (line,col,srcFile,srcLine,srcCol) => 
    console.log(`(${line},${col}) is from src file ${srcFile} at (${srcLine},${srcCol})`));
```

The lines and columns are zero-based. The specification is [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/view#).